# Bluemix liberty runtime handshake failure while accessing dashDB datasource

Tags: ibm-cloud, datasource, websphere-liberty

Suddenly I am getting an SSL error message when I am trying to access a dashDb from an auto-configured liberty server, from somewhere deep in the DB2 driver. I have verified in the deployed files that the default keystore is auto-configured into the liberty server.

What is happening here?

```
 java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
 [ERROR   ] CWPKI0022E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN CN=*.services.dal.bluemix.net, O=International Business Machines Corporation, L=Armonk, ST=New York, C=US was sent from the target host.  The signer might need to be added to local trust store /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/BluemixServer/resources/security/key.jks, located in SSL configuration alias defaultSSLConfig.  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is
 [err] java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.19.49] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, 
 or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1).  Message: java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = -4,499
 [err]     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3):

There was a change to dashDB last Friday which enhanced security requirements for cipher specs of applications accessing dashDB.   If your application was working before last week and is not now, you may need to update your cipher.

Comment: Thanks. Was this impact notified before? Just to check why did I miss this :)

Comment: There was a notification posted on the Bluemix status page.  https://status.ng.bluemix.net/   Mar 8, 2017 10:33 AM  Update dashDB service
Update Description: The IBM dashDB for Analytics Entry and SMP services and will undergo scheduled maintenance. During this maintenance window, the latest updates to the dashDB service will be applied for reliability, functional enhancements and security.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to IBM technical report via [this link](http://g01zciwas018.ahe.pok.ibm.com/support/dcf/preview.wss?host=g01zcidbs003.ahe.pok.ibm.com&db=support/swg/dmgtech.nsf&unid=C4086210EA5A6528852580F10063675D&taxOC=SS6NHC&MD=2017/03/28%2016:03:07&sid=)

Answer (score 0):

We can connect to dashDB with one of the following Liberty for java buildpacks. Please try redeploying your application and make sure that database URI has :sslConnection=true at the end.

**Build packs**

- buildpack_liberty-for-java_v3.8-20170308-1507.zip (newest)
- buildpack_liberty-for-java_v3.4.1-20161030-2241.zip (oldest)